# How to make the same speed between sets of points? Using lerp

Tags: java, libgdx

So I'm making a game where a unit follows a path set by the player. The way I code this is regularly setting points, and then making the unit follow through each of those points. Here's the code for the movement:

```
Vector2 goal = unitPath.getVertex().cpy();
if(alpha >= 1){
    unitPath.nextVertex();
    goal = unitPath.getVertex();
    lastPosition = new Vector2 (getX() + getOriginX(), getY()+getOriginY());
    alpha = 0;
}

System.out .println(alpha);
alpha += dt * speed;

Vector2 position = lastPosition.cpy();
if(goal != null){
    position.lerp(goal, alpha);
    this.centerAtPosition(position.x, position.y);
}
```

Here's the code for how each point is set:

```
Vector2 screenCoord = BattleScreen.getViewport().unproject(new Vector2(screenX, screenY));

if (new Vector2(screenCoord.x - currentVert.x, screenCoord.y - currentVert.y).len() > diagonal())
{
    unitPath.addVertices(screenCoord.x, screenCoord.y);

    currentVert = screenCoord.cpy();
}
```

The problem I was having was that between every two points, the speed with which the unit crosses the two points changes. This is because the speed of the mouse moving changes the distance between each point. I want to make it so that it has the same speed between each point.

So my question is two-fold:
how do I make the speed the same between each point?
is there a better of doing this then the way I'm doing right now?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I find your code hard to follow, but point is that you have your horizontal speed (i.e. `Vx`) and vertical speed (`Vy`). `Vx^2 + Vy^2` must be equal to `V^2`, where `V` is total speed.

So after you calculate your speed you should "normalize" it. Calculate total speed you have and compare it to speed you want to achieve. I.e. you calculated total speed 4, but you want your units to move at speed 2, then it means that your units are moving twice faster so you have to divide your Vx and Vy speed components with 2.

Hope that this makes some sense to you.